# when i update/edit data is duplicated instead of being updated in django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

data is duplicated instead of being updated in django, please help me to overcome this i also tried update method but issues i have faced is image not displayed, therefore i is used save method which will save and make copy of anthor object which i dont want. it should update the same object.

**views.py**

```
def EuAdmin(request, pk):
        pi = EmailDb.objects.get(id=pk)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            institution = request.POST.get('institution', '')
            fullname = request.POST.get('fullname', '')
            email = request.POST.get('email', '')
            contact = request.POST.get('contact', '')
            position = request.POST.get('position', '')
            uploadd = request.FILES.get('upload', '')
            sdata = EmailDb(institution=institution, fullname=fullname, contact=contact, email=email, position=position, uploaddata=uploadd)
            sdata.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/eadmin")
        return render(request, 'NEC/eupdate.html', {'pi': pi})
```

**models.py**

```
class EmailDb(models.Model):
    institution = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    fullname = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    contact = models.IntegerField()
    email = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True, null=True)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    uploaddata = models.FileField(upload_to='appointment_letter')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fullname
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you create a *new* `EmailDb` object. You can edit the one with:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404


def EuAdmin(request, pk):
    pi = get_object_or_404(EmailDb, pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        institution = request.POST.get('institution', '')
        fullname = request.POST.get('fullname', '')
        email = request.POST.get('email', '')
        contact = request.POST.get('contact', '')
        position = request.POST.get('position', '')
        uploaded = request.FILES.get('upload', '')
        pi.institution = institution
        pi.fullname = fullname
        pi.contact = contact
        pi.email = email
        pi.position = position
        pi.uploaddata = uploaded
        pi.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/eadmin')
    return render(request, 'NEC/eupdate.html', {'pi': pi})
```

---

> **Note**: It is better to use a [**`Form`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/)
> than to perform manual validation and cleaning of the data. A `Form` will not
> only simplify *rendering* a form in HTML, but it also makes it more convenient
> to *validate* the input, and *clean* the data to a more convenient type.

---

> **Note**: Models normally have no `Db` suffix. A model is not a table, it is stored in a relational database as a table, but even then it has extra logic like validators, managers, etc.

---

> **Note**: Please use an [**`EmailField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#emailfield) instead of a [**`CharField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#charfield) to store an email address, this can do validation to check if the entered data is indeed an email address.

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.comen/stable/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

Answer (score 0):

```
sdata = EmailDb(institution=institution, fullname=fullname, contact=contact, email=email, position=position, uploaddata=uploadd)
sdata.save()
```

This performs an **`INSERT SQL`** statement.

Since you already have object just set the value and call save() as

```
def EuAdmin(request, pk):
    pi = EmailDb.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        institution = request.POST.get('institution', '')
        fullname = request.POST.get('fullname', '')
        email = request.POST.get('email', '')
        contact = request.POST.get('contact', '')
        position = request.POST.get('position', '')
        uploaded = request.FILES.get('upload', '')
        pi.institution = institution
        pi.fullname = fullname
        pi.contact = contact
        pi.email = email
        pi.position = position
        pi.uploaddata = uploaded
        pi.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/eadmin")
    return render(request, 'NEC/eupdate.html', {'pi': pi})
```